# Экспортированная моделька из Blender в three.js (json) не корректно освещается от DirectionalLight

Tags: three.js, blender

Создаю простой элемент в блендере.
Экспортирую его в для three js (json).
Экспортирует данные обхект в three js на сцену. В результате этот экспортированный объект некорректно освещается источником света DirectionalLight. (Так же на этой сцене имеется созданный в самом three js объект который корректно освещается)

[image: Источник света направлен сверху вниз (_dirLight.position.set(0, 400, 0))]

Получается что объект сам отображеатся относительно осей верно, а вот освещение перепутано по осям z и y. Так как если направить источник света по оси x, то всё корректно

[image: Источник света направлен от нас (_dirLight.position.set(400, 0, 0))]

Если кто-нибудь знает решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено:

```
mMesh.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
mMesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Знаю что это маловероятно.** Но попробуй сделать Flip Normals в блендере.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]